# You can edit a message after you delete it, and it shows up as the latest revision **before** deletion

Tags: bug, chat

[As shown in this link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/10529538/history), if you edit a message after you delete it, the thing edited **after** it was deleted is said to be "the last version before deletion".

Steps to reproduce:

1. Write a message in chat.
2. Hit the edit button.
3. Delete the message.
4. Edit the message and confirm.
5. Check history.

[image]

Comment: ...why would you do that, though? :P Also, clicking that link results in a Page Not Found

Comment: I'm confused. The history looks fine to me... said, deleted, edited. It's in order... so what exactly is the problem you're trying to convey?

Comment: You might need to add screenshots with free hand circles.

Comment: @animuson The history is fine, but "Wrong link" can't be the "Last version before deletion" since it was submitted *after* the deletion. The real bug is likely that you can even do that in the first place, though.

Comment: On the off-chance that anyone actually wants to fix this, please know that I've used it before to clean up tracks when someone accidentally posted their password into chat...

Comment: @Shog9 is this a [meta-tag:status-wontfix] then?